# High-End Ubuntu Desktop Still Feels not as smooth

Tags: ati

I finally managed to get high-end system for myself and I have to say my main OS Still Windows but Ubuntu get more and more of my attention. I'll list my specs later but here is my question. I am not sure how to exactly explain it only word I can come up with is "Smooth". Let's say in Windows all fade window transitions and pages, graphics, windows, programs when dragging window all extremely smooth and liquid fluid. In Ubuntu it's not. I mean all drivers installed, games in Steam let's say are all good , high frame rate to graphic drivers are working. Programs open in milliseconds but I still feel sluggish. Again not so much how things are getting opened but I guess visually I don't feel smooth. Let's say I take chrome window when it's not maximized and just drag chrome window around screen, and it's almost like at that time instead of having 60hz refresh rate I am getting like 30hz. I don't know may be I'll do recording or something. On that note is there a Fraps (or similar) for Linux ? So I can record and see fps on screen at all times ?

X99 Deluxe Motherboard
i7 5930K CPU
16GB DDR4 2800 Corsair Memory
OCZ Vertex 2 SSD for Ubuntu Installation.
Samsung 850 Pro 256GB x2 in RAID0 for Windows Installation
Asus R9 290X GPU

There we have it, that thing should rip anything ... I think.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the issue may be a graphics driver issue.  From your description. You might be running a generic VGA compatible driver which is not taking advantage of your 290X. Run this command: 'lshw -numeric -C display' and get back to us with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips and tricks to make ubuntu much more responsive.

1. Change Swap

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   Add this entry at the end and save:

   ```
   vm.swappiness=10
   ```
2. Get the following Tweak Tools:

   Ubuntu Tweak ( `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak` )

   Tweak Tool ( `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` )

   Unity Tweak ( `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` )

   Dconf Editor ( `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` )

   Compiz Config Editor ( `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra -y` )

   Review each section of each tool and modify as desired
3. Get Bleachbit

   I suggest downloading the newest version as the one in the repository(Software Center) is old.  You can download it here:
   http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux
4. Review the following sites and modify your system as needed.

   https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/first#TOC-Decrease-the-swap-use-very-important-

   https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

   http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-software-linux.htm?page=0,0#Introduction

   http://smashingweb.info/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-for-perfect-desktop/

   http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920

   http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1404.htm

Check FPS

Open terminal, type `glxgears` and hit enter.

Hope this info helps a bit.

**One other awesome tool I use is CPU Indicator**

Open Terminal and install:

`sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq`

Then run:

`indicator-cpufreq` in terminal to launch

Reboot! You will see the icon in the top bar of unity interface.

Right click icon and select the fastest CPU speed or desired speed! This tool is AWESOME and will help a TON!

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try things you suggested because my system is fast but it's not butter smooth if you know what I mean. I mean GUI feels not as good, and I am sure this is not Linux thing because I see there is no problem with Linux/Unix based system as we all know and love OSX. So yeah I want that smooth :D

Comment: Using CompizConfig to disable effects helps with 'smoothness' and clocking your CPU to its fastest speed will help a lot.   Please mark as correct if this helped, I can use the points.  Also I have a saved configuration file for CCSM, if you want it so you can import it let me know.